# Declare is not valid at this position, expecting

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Have Declares which are giving unbefore seen errors, that have attempted to find the solution of. As well as weird as have previous procedures which use same syntax but do not throw any errors

This is for a procedure which uses cursors to retrieve information from a table, then insert it into another table, which is done so that the information within may be used to be able calculate a total, which is passed along along with some required values

`````
BEGIN
     DECLARE fin INT DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE pol VARCHAR(30) default '';
     DECLARE total_accrued decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00';
     DECLARE total_paid decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0';
     DECLARE TOTAL DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00';
     DECLARE user_pol varchar(45) default '';

     DECLARE c3 CURSOr FOR SELECT total_accrued FROM fn_policy_mast;
     DECLARE c4 CURSOR FOr SELECT total_amount_paid FROM fn_policy_mast;
     DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR SELECt policy_number FROM fn_policy_mast;
     DECLARE c1 CURSOr FOR SELECT balance FROM fn_policy_mast;

    -- DECLARE d_policy CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT cod_policy FROM fn_policy_mast;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = TRUE;

     OPEN c1;
     OPEN c2;
     OPEN c3;
     OPEN c4;
    -- OPEN d_policy;

     read_loop: LOOP

     FETCH c3 INTO total_accrued;
     FETCH c4 INTO total_paid;
     FETCH c2 INTO pol;
     set total = 0;
    -- FETCH d_policy INTO user_pol;

     -- IF user_pol = pol then
      set total_accrued = (SELECT SUM(monthly_premium) FROM col_trans_log WHERE policy_number LIKE pol);
      set total_paid = (SELECT SUM(transaction_amount) FROM col_Trans_log WHERE policy_number LIKE pol);

      set total =  total_paid - total_accrued;     
     -- END IF;

    -- set TOTAL = (total_accrued-total_paid);
     UPDATE fn_policy_mast set balance = TOTAL WHERE policy_number like pol;


     IF fin=TRUE THEN 
        LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;


     -- INSERT STATEMENTS HERE
    --  set total = 0;
     END LOOP;  
     select * FROM fn_policy_mast;
     close c1;
     close c2;
     CLOSE c3;
     CLOSE c4;

END//
DELIMITER ;````

Expected result to run, accepting the declares, actual experience is thaere is some form of syntax wrong, as it does not properly recognise the declare statements

This is the error message : Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
`````

Comment: The code looks fine. Could you add the exact error message? Also, do you get that error when defining the procedure or when running it?

Comment: Will do so now, when running it

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE total_paid decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0'
```

Is this the line?
Have you tried changing the default to '0.00' ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I made a dumb mistake and forget to include the delimiter before the procedure, afterwards it works.

Simply include a "Delimiter //" before the procedure

Comment: This is only required if you write your routine in a normal SQL editor (which can have more than one SQL statement and hence needs the delimiter). However, if you create your routine with the routine editor (right click on the in the schema tree node for procedures or functions -> Create ...) you will get an editor, which only allows that routine to be written and hence needs no delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

However, a stored procedure consists of multiple statements separated by a semicolon (`;`).

If you use a MySQL client program to define a stored procedure that contains semicolon characters, the MySQL client program will not treat the whole stored procedure as a single statement, but many statements.

Therefore, you must redefine the delimiter temporarily so that you can pass the whole stored procedure to the server as a single statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name()
BEGIN[enter link description here][1]
  -- statements
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please refer attached [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/) for more detail.